# Getting Marvin Labs SCSS syntax plugin to work for Notepad++

Tags: sass, notepad++

I have tried following advice I saw here about downloading Marvin Lab's git plugin to have syntax highlight for SCSS on Notepad++ but nothing happened.

I do not have a `User Defined Dialogue` in the `View menu` but imported the files through `Settings>Import>Import Theme` (when I tried to import through plugin it wouldn't allow me to select the Marvin plugins). I closed out and reopened repeatedly, tried reloading the files, importing the theme again and there is still no syntax highlighting is showing up.

Any clues to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem just this morning. Here are the steps I took (using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) v6.5.1 and the July 2013 commit from [Marvin Labs' scss syntax plugin repo](https://github.com/marvinlabs/notepad-plus-plus-scss-syntax-highlighting/)):

1. Language > Define your language...
2. Import...
3. (Select the XML file)
4. Close any .scss files currently open in Notepad++
5. Close & reopen Notepad++

At this point the syntax highlighting should be applied automatically to any .scss files you open. If it isn't, you should still be able to manually apply it: with your .scss file open and active, go to the *Language* menu and select "SCSS-Light" or "SCSS-Dark" (whichever you installed) from that list.

Comment: Note that following these instructions for NPPv6.6.7 result in a "Fail to import." error for me when executing step 3

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for this problem.

Keep your scss files in a subdir called sCSS and keep *.css for their file name extension.  That way Notepad++ will be able to edit them reasonably well.

Then put your generated css files into another subdir called CSS.  Note, they will also have a .css filename extension, so you need to not mix them up.  You might want to add a short text file to this subdir explaining what is going on.

(If you want you could rename these something else, and then just change your html meta tag to use whatever filename extension you give them but I'm not sure that's a good idea and am not going to do it myself.)

I tried to come up with a way for Notepad++ to support scss by configuring it or hacking it and I even considered building a plugin for it.  But it's too much trouble to do that when there is this much simpler solution to the problem at hand.

I know this is sort of a hack, but building a plugin for Notepad++ is beyond my capabilities right now and it's pretty clear that this other plug in does not work (or at least does not work anymore).